How to use algolia vue instant search tag <ais-refinement-list> refine method first time?
I am using algolia instant search. I have a scenario where I want to refine the results as I navigate from categories page to the deals page where the filters and products are being listed. I send the category name that is selected on Categories page to Deals page, I have achieved the feature that the checkbox is pre-selected with that category but it does not filter the products.
I am receiving the name of category in props:
<ais-refinement-list attribute="category_name" :transform-items="transformItems" operator="and" :limit="100">
    <template v-slot="{
      items,
      isShowingMore,
      isFromSearch,
      canToggleShowMore,
      refine,
      toggleShowMore,
    }">

      <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.value" class="flex items-center space-x-2 mb-2" @click="refine(item.value)">
        <Checkbox :id="item.value" :checked="isChecked(item.value)"
          @update:checked="handleCheckboxChange(item.value)" />
        <Label :for="item.value" class="space-x-2 font-body text-sm text-[#002401]">
          {{ toCamelCase(item.value) }}
          <span class="text-[10px] text-[#7A7A7A]">({{ item.count.toLocaleString() }})</span>
        </Label>
      </div>
      
    </template>
  </ais-refinement-list>




const props = defineProps({
selectedCategory: { type: String, required: true },

});


Now I want to refine the products on the base of the selectedCategory. Currently the refine() method only works on @click. Is there any method to access this refine method and call it on onMounted or change its state?
I tried to do it with :transform-items="transformItems" method as it is available in docs but it does not work.

Please fix formatting; see formatting help
